# Strange defect on TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

On one of Beamer slides for my dissertation defense I construct a TikZ diagram, representing my research software's workflow. It works fine with one exception: there is a "defect" on the east side of the "ready4EDA" block (extra arrow end tip + wrong arrow start tip). It seems strange to me and, based on the similarity of code for other block definitions, I even suspect that it might be a software defect (not very likely) or conflict between LaTeX or TikZ packages. I would appreciate comments and, preferably, solutions on getting rid of that "defect". The MWE follows.

[image]

**Notes:** 1) I would like to stay with this (standard TikZ) implementation; 2) I use `smartdiagram` package for some other diagrams in my presentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, trees, shadows, shapes, backgrounds, calc, fadings, positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, intersections, fit}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{gray!5}{gray!20}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\newcommand{\DISSflossWorkflow}{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=8cm, auto, >=stealth]

  \tikzstyle{block}= [rectangle, ultra thick, rounded corners, draw=blue, fill=blue!20, minimum height=1.25cm, minimum width=32mm, align=center, inner sep=0.5em]
  \tikzstyle{arrow}= [ultra thick, ->, >=stealth]

  \node[block] (dataHeader) {\color{red}\textbf{Data}};
  \node[block] (softHeader) [right of = dataHeader, node distance = 4cm] {\color{red}\textbf{Software}};
  %\draw[->] (a) -- (b);
  \node[block] (artiHeader) [right of = softHeader, node distance = 4cm] {\color{red}\textbf{Artifacts}};
  %\draw[->] (b) -- (c);
  % \draw[-] (\xcoord[west]{dataHeader}, \ycoord[south]{dataHeader} - 1) -- (\xcoord[east]{artiHeader}, \ycoord[south]{dataHeader} - 1);
  \node[block] (dataSources) [below of = dataHeader, node distance = 1.5cm]{Data Sources};
  \node[block] (softImport) [right of = dataSources, node distance = 4cm] {import};
  \draw[arrow] (dataSources) -- (softImport);

  \node[block] (dataCache) [below of = dataSources, node distance = 1.5cm] {cache};
  \draw[arrow] (softImport) -- (dataCache);

  \node[block] (softPrepare) [right of = dataCache, node distance = 4cm] {prepare};
  \draw[arrow] (dataCache) -- (softPrepare);

  \node[block] (dataTransform) [below of = dataCache, node distance = 1.5cm] {transform};
  \draw[arrow] (softPrepare) -- (dataTransform);

  \node[block] (dataReady4EDA) [below of = dataCache, node distance = 1.5cm] {ready4EDA};
  \draw[arrow] (dataTransform) -- (dataReady4EDA);

  \node[block] (softEDA) [right of = dataReady4EDA, node distance = 4cm] {EDA};
  \draw[arrow] (dataReady4EDA) -- (softEDA);

  \node[block] (artiEDA) [right of = softEDA, node distance = 4cm] {EDA Report};
  \draw[arrow] (softEDA) -- (artiEDA);

  \node[block] (dataReady4EFA) [below of = dataReady4EDA, node distance = 1.5cm] {ready4EFA};
  \draw[arrow] (softEDA) -- (dataReady4EFA);

  \node[block] (softEFA) [right of = dataReady4EFA, node distance = 4cm] {EFA};
  \draw[arrow] (dataReady4EFA) -- (softEFA);

  \node[block] (artiEFA) [right of = softEFA, node distance = 4cm] {EFA Report};
  \draw[arrow] (softEFA) -- (artiEFA);

  \node[block] (dataReady4CFA) [below of = dataReady4EFA, node distance = 1.5cm] {ready4CFA};
  \draw[arrow] (softEFA) -- (dataReady4CFA);

  \node[block] (softCFA) [right of = dataReady4CFA, node distance = 4cm] {CFA};
  \draw[arrow] (dataReady4CFA) -- (softCFA);

  \node[block] (artiCFA) [right of = softCFA, node distance = 4cm] {CFA Report};
  \draw[arrow] (softCFA) -- (artiCFA);

  \node[block] (dataReady4SEM) [below of = dataReady4CFA, node distance = 1.5cm] {ready4SEM};
  \draw[arrow] (softCFA) -- (dataReady4SEM);

  \node[block] (softSEM) [right of = dataReady4SEM, node distance = 4cm] {SEM};
  \draw[arrow] (dataReady4SEM) -- (softSEM);

  \node[block] (artiSEM) [right of = softSEM, node distance = 4cm] {SEM Report};
  \draw[arrow] (softSEM) -- (artiSEM);

  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Research Software: Workflow}

\centering
\scalebox{0.7}{\DISSflossWorkflow}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try cutting this down to an MWE yourself? `dataReady4EDA` and `dataTransform` are both positioned identically (`below of=dataCache`) so when you try `\draw[arrow] (dataTransform) -- (dataReady4EDA);` you get this spurious arrow going nowhere.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Good catch! Thank you so much - I guess, I initially planned a bit more expanded diagram, hence `dataTransform` block definition, but later decided against it (probably due to size constraints and the fact that data transformation is part of `prepare` anyway). I've already updated corresponding code and it fixed the issue. If you'll convert you comment into an answer, I will be happy to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

The nodes `dataReady4EDA` and `dataTransform` are both positioned identically (`below of=dataCache`) so when you try

```
\draw[arrow] (dataTransform) -- (dataReady4EDA);
```

you get this spurious arrow going nowhere. You can comment that line (or reposition your nodes) to correct the problem.

---

Other notes:

1. You might consider using TikZ's `scale` option or `font=\small`, etc. instead of the `\scalebox`, then the font sizes used will be consistent with other design choices in the presentation rather than some arbitrary size.
2. For new documents, prefer the new `\tikzset{<name>/.style={<style-defn>}}` over the old `\tikzstyle` method. (See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles))
3. You load the new `positioning` library but use the older syntax `right of = <node>` rather than the positioning library syntax `right=of <node>`.

Comment: Thank you again! Your notes on code improvement are appreciated as well.